# Platform / PaaS Questions - Can these be included as part of the Survey?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2018

The Survey covers "platforms" off at a high level, with elements such as IBM Watson, Saleforce - but what data is available on deeper API and Platform usage?

For instance - when going down into the Mapping category - which API's are most used?

This will become even more important as AI APIs (SageMaker, Watson etc) begin to become more and more integrated into the ecosystem.

Is any of this information available in the deeper survey results? If not - is there scope to include these "ePaas" APIs in future surveys?

Comment: Mmm, I don't know. This would be interesting, but it seems like overloading a survey that is already really, really big and complex.

Comment: I thought they wanted us to write an AI that would fill that. Didn't you get the memo @Pekka웃 ? :P

Comment: @Christian but which platform should I use to build it? Which is the most used?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - I agree, and there are so many of these platforms now - at the same time it would be great to see the relative popularity of these.

Comment: @Pekka웃  - is there any thing that could be done by indexing how many SO tags are used?